# Measuring the amplitude of a nV signal of known frequency and phase using AD633

Tags: detection, mixer, small-signal

I am wondering if there is a circuit to measure the amplitude of a sinusoidal signal of known frequency and phase that is induced in a pickup coil. The amplitude would be in the range of 0nV to approximately 100nV and the frequency is 15kHz. In addition to this signal, there are other signals present in the pickup coil, mostly at 5kHz (this frequency is referred to as omega_0).

I was thinking of using a principle shown in the image below:

[image]

The main idea is to mix the received signal with a known reference signal at 15kHz=3*omega_0. The 15kHz signal that is picked up by the coil should generate a DC voltage at the output of the multiplier which is then integrated.
$$ V_{out}=\int \frac{\hat{V}}{2}(1-\cos(6\omega_{0}t))dt + \int500\mathrm{\mu V}\sin(\omega_{0}t)\sin(3\omega_0t)$$.

### Simulation without integrator

I tried simulating such a circuit in LTSpice using the [AD633 model from LT](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad633.html) by applying a small sinusoidal signal of 1mV to it but the simulation result don't make sense. I would expect the output of the AD633 to be
$$ v_{mult}=v_{pickup}*v_{oscref}/10 $$
However, the output of the AD633 is much higher (mV range rather than uV range).

So I'm wondering where the issue with my simulation is or if what I am trying to achieve is even feasible using perhaps another chip or circuit?

[image]
[image]

### Simulation with Integrator

Here's another simulation including the integrator. Again, the output of the AD633 seems weird. I would expect it to be both positive and negative but it seems to be a strictly positive voltage at roughly 5mV which saturates the integrator.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Red and green traces look about the same amplitude so, why do you say one should be microvolts rather than millivolts? DC offsets in the AD633 are going to be your main issue.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. The plot in question has two y axes (one is on the right). The output of the AD633 seems weird. I made another simulation including the integrator and I expected the voltage output of the mixer to be both positive and negative but it only seemed to hover around 4.5mV causing the integrator to saturate.

Comment: Don't downmix so your wanted signal is at DC. Too many bad things happen at DC to swamp your signal - DC offsets, LO leakage, 1/f noise. Always mix down to an IF, digitise the IF, and synchronously detect digitally.

Comment: (scales) OK, I see it now. The DC offsets in the mixer cause your red trace to remain as mainly 15 kHz and not 30 kHz - try offsetting the DC on one of the inputs bit by bit and watch for the right amplitude at 30 kHz but, as Spehro has intimated, your signals are fall too small to be useful in a real circuit of this type.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is good.  This is the basis of the [lock-in amplifier.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-in_amplifier#Basic_principles)

The thing is that what you want is not the AC output signal, but rather the filtered **DC** from the output.  The DC component is proportional to the product of the amplitude of the signals - but only when the reference signal and the detected signal are at the same frequency.  This type of amplifier rejects frequencies that don't match the reference signal.

Your output (vmult) shows a DC offset.  You'd want to filter out the 15kHz (and higher) stuff.  To make the detector more sensitive, you'd use a filter with a lower cutoff frequency - which, naturally, also slows the response to changes in the input.

The DC offset in your plots looks too high.  That's to be expected.  The [AD633 datasheet](https://www.tme.eu/Document/ce5356ac4efb480c752b9e53289e2634/AD633ARZ-Analog-Devices.pdf) mentions several sources of error and gives some hints for reducing it.

In simulation, you can replace the AC inputs with a DC input.  You can easily calculate the correct output for the DC, then see how much offset the chip itself is producing.  You then apply the hints from the datasheet to reduce the error sources and check your results.  Once you've got it trimmed to produce accurate results at your expected signal levels you can switch back to AC signals.

You'll have to include adjustable trimmers in your real circuit when you build it.  You'll have to work out a procedure for trimming your real circuit to reduce the errors before you use it for your real task.

**Added:**
Note that the datasheet says the operating voltage range is from +-8V to +-18V.  You are using +-5V, which is outside the rated range.  It might work properly, it might not.  It is best to use the rated ranges.

---

Simplest would be to buy or rent a lock-in amplifier.  All of the trimming and adjustment is taken care of for you.  If you need accurate, verifiable results, then this would be the better way to go.

If this is for a personal experiment or for learning the principles, then go with the AD633, but do take a good look at the AD633 datasheet and read up on lock-in amplifiers.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issue with the MPY633 model in LTspice. Even with correct supply voltages (+/-5V is too low) it is not giving the correct output waveform. Note that the **typical** datasheet output offset voltage is 5mV and the model may include that (in reality it can be either polarity and smaller or larger than 5mV).

In general with a synchronously demodulated tiny signal like this you want to amplify the AC signal as much as possible (without saturation) before applying it to the demodulator as the demodulator is guaranteed to have errors, perhaps large ones as in this case.

The demodulator can be as simple as a +1/-1 gain block, operated by a synchronous square wave, which is a lot easier to make with low offset than a 4-quadrant multiplier.

It's also possible to do demodulation in the digital domain, but the main thing is to get the signal up to a level where you can work with it accurately, without the signal chain at any point saturating due to the signal or due to noise (which, in many case of this ilk, can be higher amplitude than the signal).